# Using jQuery plugin with Angular 5 (Typescript) failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to integrate this plugin: https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js into a fresh Angular 5 (Typescript) application but I am facing this error:

[image]

I have installed this jQuery library using: `npm install gridstack`

Here is my code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

    constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // It works.
      $("button").click(function(){
        var div = $("div");
        div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
        div.animate({fontSize: '5em'}, "slow");
      });

      // Failed !!!
      $('.grid-stack').gridstack();

    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Hello World!
  </h1>

  <button>Start Animation</button>
  <div style="border:1px solid #555;border-radius:3px;color:white;background:#555;height:105px;width:260px;position:relative; margin-top:10px">jQuery</div>

<div class="grid-stack">
    <div class="grid-stack-item"
        data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0"
        data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-stack-item"
        data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0"
        data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Demo showing the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sidhl

Comment: Did you install this: "@types/jquery"

Comment: Yes, It's already installed !

Comment: How did you include the gridstack plugin ?

Comment: it's in question description. using: `npm install gridstack`

Comment: Installing the package does not mean that you are using it. Do you use angular cli?

Comment: Yes, I do use angular  cli, the project is generated using it.

Comment: So where do you include the gridstack.js files? In index.html or angular-cli.json ?

Comment: No where . I haven't included it in both of them.

Comment: Why should I include it in index.html if I already installed it using npm. jquery works without including it anywhere.

Comment: Because you are explicitly importing jQuery `import * as $ from 'jquery';`. See my answer below

Comment: You need to include the file in your angular cli json as well, just like you did for jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this line:

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

By:

`declare var $: any;`

Fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below.

In you component.

```
    declare var $el: JQuery;  // This is missing in your code, you have to declare $ as variable.

    @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
     })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

       ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

This should work.

Comment: Which part you have fixed ?

Comment: To use $, you have to declare it as variable, which was missing in your code.

Comment: But I have imported it from 'jquery' package. also in your code you have written `$el`.

Comment: You dont need to import. $el is there because simply $ doesnt follow naming conventions of variable in Javascript. Angular is nothing but javascript. to use $(), it must find some variable for it. This works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Also $el keeps a reference to the DOM Elements which you are trying to modify.

Comment: Still not able to make it work. can share working demo online. using : https://stackblitz.com/ for example ?

Comment: Thanks k would take time. Have you installed jQuery 3.1.1 and also make sure jQuery.min.js is referenced in index.html

Comment: The first part of my code works ! so obviously jQuery is installed. right ?

Comment: Also your response doesn't make sense. $ is working good with first part of my code. try to update it please.

Comment: What response? Which part of my code you aren't understanding please specify.

Comment: You are using gridstack plugin. Not sure about that I installed plain jQuery.

Comment: You have said in your comment " To use $, you have to declare it as variable, which was missing in your code. " .. right ? but I am already using $ without using your proposed code. the problem is not in jquery. it's in gridstack usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168045/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-badis-merabet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the gridstack js file in your `.angular-cli.json` file in the scripts sections

```
"scripts":[
//Your other dependencies, including jQuery
"../node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.js",
//other dependencies
]
```

Then make sure you stop and restart `ng serve` after modifying the config

Comment: @BadisMerabet: From a quick google search, I'd say it's probably because you forgot to add lodash

Comment: I think we are getting away from the problem :). how did you know if it's lodash or underscore ?  jQuery is working just fine without including it in .angular-cli. the error is: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).gridstack is not a function` . it's not because gridstack it's not included. IMHO it's a typing problem of typescript that I am not able to resolve.

Comment: you can play around with it here :) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sidhl?file=.angular-cli.json . thanks !

Comment: Have you tried adding installing lodash and adding it to angular-cli.json ? And I did you understand what your stackblitz is means to prove?

Comment: I have add lodash. the first error goes away. but the original error is still there : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOibd.png :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sidhl . I was trying to reproduce errors here. so you can take a look your self.

Comment: You can't modify angular-cli.json on stackblitz AFAIK, so I cannot show you actual example (you can put anything in the scripts section it won't be loaded). I managed to make your stackblitz work by including the files in index.html, but it's not good as you need to add a setTimeout to have gridstack plugin recognised, otherwise the component is loaded before the plugin is ready